# Set ANORM SELECT parameter to null

Tags: scala, select, parameters, null, anorm

I'm trying to execute SELECT statement, where parameters might have null values:

```
SQL(
      """
      SELECT id FROM devices WHERE
        name = {name}
      """)
  .on("name" -> device.name)()
  .collectFirst {
     ...
  }.getOrElse {
     ...
  }
```

`device.name` can return null. With `db.default.logStatements=true` I see that generated SQL looks like this: `SELECT id FROM devices WHERE name = NULL`.

`name = NULL` is not quite valid for Postgre SQL, but I've enabled it using `transform_null_equals`. Now when I execute SQL from log using pgAdmin, it works perfectly fine. However, ANORM does not find anything.

Following code does return result:

```
SQL(
      """
      SELECT id FROM devices WHERE
        name = NULL
      """)
  .on("name" -> device.name)()
  .collectFirst {
      ...
  }.getOrElse {
     ...
  }
```

What's wrong with it?!